# Solr no search results on new field

Tags: lucene, solr, indexing

I added a multivalue field to `schema.xml` as follows:

```
<field name="fieldsharedsite" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" /> 
<field name="fieldsharedchannelnew" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
```

When I search for a document contents, I get the following result:

```
<fieldsharedsite><item key="0">33</item></fieldsharedsite> 
<fieldsharedchannelnew><item key="0">52</item></fieldsharedchannelnew>
```

so I am sure `fieldsharedchannelnew` is in the results

When I do the following search:
`q=fieldsharedsite:33` 
I do get the document
but when I do 
`q=fieldsharedchannelnew:52`
I don't get any results.

`fieldsharedsite` has been here for a while and I'm trying to add `fieldsharedchannelnew`.
I did reindex all the content but did not help the search.

If I look at the schema browser, I have for `fieldsharedsite`:

```
 Field Type: string
 Properties:  Indexed, Multivalued, Omit Norms, Sort Missing Last
 Schema:  Indexed, Multivalued, Omit Norms, Sort Missing Last
 Index:  (unstored field)
 Index Analyzer: org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType$DefaultAnalyzer 
 Query Analyzer: org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType$DefaultAnalyzer 
 Docs:  902
```

and for `fieldsharedchannnelnew` I have:

```
 Field Type: string
 Properties:  Indexed, Multivalued, Omit Norms, Sort Missing Last
 Index Analyzer: org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType$DefaultAnalyzer 
 Query Analyzer: org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType$DefaultAnalyzer
```

What step did I miss in adding the `fieldsharedchannelnew` index? Why its not returning any results when I search for it?

Answer (score 0):

The schema browser result for the field fieldsharedchannnelnew does not indicate it is populated in the documents.
the **Docs** information is missing, as for fieldsharedsite which shows it exists in 902 docs.

```
Field Type: string
Properties:  Indexed, Multivalued, Omit Norms, Sort Missing Last
Index Analyzer: org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType$DefaultAnalyzer 
Query Analyzer: org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType$DefaultAnalyzer
```

When I search for a document contents, I get the following result:

```
<fieldsharedsite><item key="0">33</item></fieldsharedsite> 
<fieldsharedchannelnew><item key="0">52</item></fieldsharedchannelnew>
```

As the fields are not stored, the fields would not be returned with the results.
Is this the data you are feeding Solr ? how do they appear in results ?
Are you using value as is or want to use copyfield ?

You may mark the fields as stored and reindex the contents and check if they are returned with the results and the schema browser shows the Docs information.
If so, you should be able to search it as well.

Comment: The following is what is returned by solr when I search for a document:
 
<fieldsharedsite><item key="0">33</item></fieldsharedsite> 
<fieldsharedchannelnew><item key="0">52</item></fieldsharedchannelnew>

so I can see that the indexes is returned with the results. but when I search against
it (fieldsharedcahnnelnew:52) I don't get the document. If I do fieldsharedsite:33 I do get it.

Comment: Both indexes are not stored (in schema.xml):
<field name="fieldsharedsite" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />  
<field name="fieldsharedchannelnew" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" /> 
 
Why would the Docs information be missing?

Comment: the docs information shows how many docs have the field populated even if it is not stored, which in the case above does not show any meaning the field does not hold any values.